# Why is EXIM not able to verify sender?

Tags: email, ubuntu-14.04, exim, exim4

Puzzling problem sending emails from one server to another.

Sending from `Server-01 pr@example.camp` TO `Server-02 eman@example.edu.au`

Server 02 bounces with `sender verify fail for <pr@example.camp>: Unrouteable address`

On Server-02 running `dig MX example.camp` resolves fine with:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mus.camp.               2869    IN      MX      10 server01-aus.emanwebdesign.com.
mus.camp.               2869    IN      MX      0 server01-aus.emanwebdesign.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mus.camp.               2869    IN      NS      ns10.domaincontrol.com.
mus.camp.               2869    IN      NS      ns09.domaincontrol.com.
```

Also from Server-02 I can telnet into port 25 of mus.camp and verify the existence of the email address (pr@...).

Any clues as to why Exim's sender verify is failing?

**Edit**
`exim -bvs pr@example.camp` returns

`pr@example.camp failed to verify: Unrouteable address`

Comment: Do you have (root) access to the receiving mailserver? Can you add the according sender verify configuration to your question?

Comment: @geruetzel, Yes I have root access. What do you mean by 'sender verify configuration'?

Comment: does `exim -bvs pr@example.camp` give you any additional info for why the sender is not routeable? also, is this the only email address that is denied as sender? have you tried others? please also update your question with your receiving exim's ACL section. If you are using split file configuration, can you please post all files in conf.d/acl? am i correct that the sender's mail address is pr@mus.camp? my exim accepts it as sender...

Comment: yes, that's the correct sender's mail address. The command returns: `pr@mus.camp failed to verify: Unrouteable address`

Comment: Okay but the other questions I asked? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out the problem was that the mus.camp domain was originally hosted on Server-02 but then moved to Server-01. Server-02 however was still trying to lookup the email address within itself instead of going to Server-01.

To solve the problem I deleted the mail and dns records from Server-02. (using VestaCP).